# Testing routerOnActivate in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to check my routerOnActivate method is being called correctly but need to pass in params, however i can't find any documentation on how to do this.

For simplicity the method is say

```
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment): void {
  this.uniqueId = curr.getParam('uniqueId');

}
```

and i want to do something like

```
it('should work', inject([TestComponentBuilder, MockBackend], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
tcb.createAsync(TestComponent)
    .then((rootTC:any) => {
        let componentInstance = rootTC.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
        spyOn(componentInstance, 'routerOnActivate');
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => {
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                status: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({message:'found'})
            })));
        });
        rootTC.detectChanges();
        expect(componentInstance.routerOnActivate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(componentInstance.uniqueId).toBe(123);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

So the way i've resolved was to create RouteSegment and pass that into the method directly, this allows me to check that method works, its not exactly how i wanted to test it, as i wanted to make sure the routerOnActivate was also fired when the component/route loads. But its a start.

```
let segments = new RouteSegment([], {'uniqueId': 1234}, null, null, null);
componentInstance.routerOnActivate(segments);
```